# How to pull the right keys and values from jq into an array in bash shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, dialog, jq

I have a json file that is formatted like so:

```
{
  "ServerName1": {
    "localip": "192.168.1.1",
    "hostname": "server1"
  },
  "ServerName2": {
    "localip": "192.168.1.2",
    "hostname": "server2"
  },
  "ServerName3": {
    "localip": "192.168.1.3",
    "hostname": "server3"
  }
}
```

And i am trying to write a shell script that uses Dialog to create a menu to run an ssh connection command. I'm parsing with jq, but can't get past the first object level. We have a lot of servers and this will make connecting to them a lot easier. I have the Dialog statement working fine with static data, but we are trying to populate it with a json file with the rest of the data. So i am killing myself trying to figure out how to get just the localip and hostname either into an array to loop into the Dialog command or something that will effectively do the same thing and al I get it it to do so far is spit out

`Servername1 = {"localip":"192.168.1.1","hostname":"server1"}`

on each line. I'm a shell script newbie but this is messing with sanity now.

This is the jq command that I've been working with so far:

```
jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" config.json
```

This is the Dialog command that works well with static data:

```
callssh(){
  clear
  ssh $1@$2
}

## Display Menu ##
dialog --clear --title "SSH Relayer"\
    --menu "Please choose which server \n\
    with which you would like to connect" 15 50 4 \ 
    "Server 1" "192.168.1.1"\
    "Server 2" "192.168.1.2"\
    "Server 3" "192.168.1.3"\
    Exit "Exit to shell" 2>"${INPUT}"

menuitem=$(<"${INPUT}")

case $menuitem in
    "Server 1") callssh $sshuser 192.168.1.1;;
    "Server 2") callssh $sshuser 192.168.1.2;;
    "Server 3") callssh $sshuser 192.168.1.3;;
    Exit) clear 
          echo "Bye!";;
esac
```

Thanks for any help or pointing in the right direction.

Comment: This is the jq command I'm using right now. I got it from my research here.
```jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" config.json```
And I've been looking through everything I can find for a few hours now. I can go find a list of the more promising entries I've read if that helps you.

Comment: Can you share the jq command in the question ?and spell out the actual requested output. Will be much easier to read (vs a comment)

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you showed "the Dialog statement [that is] working fine with static data".

Comment: Okay added that bit of the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

To create a bash array mapping hostnames to ip addresses based on config.json:

```
declare -A ip_of

# Emit lines of the form:
# hostname localip (without quotation marks)
function hostname_ip {
 local json="$1"
 jq -r '.[] | "\(.hostname) \(.localip)"' "$json"
}

while read -r hostname ip ; do
    ip_of["$hostname"]="$ip"
done < <(hostname_ip config.json)
```

You can loop through this bash array like so:

```
for hostname in "${!ip_of[@]}" ; do
  echo hostname=$hostname "=>" ${ip_of[$hostname]}
done
```

For example, assuming the "dialog" presents the hostnames,
you can replace the `case` statement by:

```
callssh "$sshuser" "${ip_of[$menuitem]}"
```